# Dropdown within a Button Group resizing issue for the Table Row

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, datatables, bootstrap-modal

So, basically, I am using Datatable via ajax to load up records in a table that is placed within a modal, that pops up on a button click. I do have a column which marks the Action for that particular record. The status column is a button group drop-down. so whenever I click on any row's drop-down arrow, the row resizes. Is there any way to stop that happening? I have tried overscroll property, but that doesn't work. Or is it behaving like that because of the Modal? Any suggestions?

[image: Before Clicking Dropdown]

[image: After Clicking Dropdown]

Above you can easily notice the change in the width of the first record before and after the click.

## The Necessary Jquery Code for the Action Block goes below

```
settingsHtml = `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div class="btn-group chargeability">
        <button type="button" class="btn bg-indigo waves-effect current-schedule-chargeable" data-id="`+d[0][i].id+`" style="width:115px" title="Schedule Chargeable Setting">`+ chargeable +`</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn bg-indigo dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="position: relative;z-index: 99999;">
            <li style="background:#f9f5e9;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-value="1" data-lead="`+d[0][i].lead_id+`" data-id="`+d[0][i].id+`" class="schedule-chargeable waves-effect waves-block">Yes</a></li>
            <li style="background:#f9f5e9"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-value="0" data-lead="`+d[0][i].lead_id+`" data-id="`+d[0][i].id+`" class="schedule-chargeable waves-effect waves-block">No</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>`;
```

Comment: show us your code please

Comment: It is a bit difficult for me to show the whole code because the code is chunked and is appended to the table at the last.

Comment: at least the neccessary code

Comment: I have added the related code.